# Manipulate for loop to increment by specific value? - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

To generate a list of prime numbers using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, in Java, I can do this:

```
public static void processSieve(boolean[] sieve)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < sieve.length; i++)
        sieve[i] = true;

    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(sieve.length); i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == true)
        {
            for (int j = i * 2; j < sieve.length; j += i)
                sieve[j] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

However, Python doesn't have C-Style for loops, so I am forced to use a while loop to accomplish the same thing:

```
def processSieve(sieve):

    sieve = [True for i in range(HOWMANY + 1)]
    sieve[0], sieve[1], i, j = False, False, 2, 0

    while i <= math.sqrt(len(sieve)):

        if sieve[i] == True:
            j = i * 2

            while j < len(sieve):
                sieve[j] = False
                j += i

        i += 1
```

Is it possible to use for..in loop in Python to emulate the Java for loop written above? Or am I forced to only use a while loop?

Comment: `for i in range(lower,upper+1,step)`

Comment: for what it's worth, I think the `while` version is more readable. also, you can shorten `if sieve[i] == True:` to `if sieve[i]:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop:

```
>>> for i in range(2,10,3):
...   print i
...
2
5
8
```

> range(...)
>       range([start,] stop[, step]) -> list of integers
>
> ```
> Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
> range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]; start (!) defaults to 0.
> When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
> For example, range(4) returns [0, 1, 2, 3].  The end point is omitted!
> These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
> ```

So

```
for (int j = i * 2; j < sieve.length; j += i)
```

can be "translated" to:

```
for j in range(i*2, len(sieve), i):
```

Comment: Shoot, I did not know you could specify a step in the range function. I can't accept an answer for another 10 minutes, but this answered my question.

Comment: `for (int j = i * 2; j < sieve.length; j += i)` is equivalent to `for j in range(i*2, len(sieve), i)`, isn't it?

Comment: @ch3ka yep, I have just realized that. I didn't see that the iteration was with `j`. Thought that it was something like `for(i=0;i<10; somethingUnrelatedToI() `

Answer (score 1):

1.Python has a `for in` loop, and it's often used with [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

2.since `math.sqrt` generate float number, you should use [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to get a integer

3.there's no need to init `i` in python

```
def processSieve(sieve):  
    sieve = [True for i in range(HOWMANY + 1)]  
    sieve[0], sieve[1], j = False, False, 0
    for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(len(sieve))):
        if sieve[i] == True:
            j = i * 2
            while j < len(sieve):
                sieve[j] = False
                j += i
        i += 1
```